# How can I change style for header wenzhixin bootstrap-table?

Tags: bootstrap-table, tableheader

I am trying to change header style a table with wenzhixin bootstrap-table.But class="info" doesn't work.
there is a code:

```html
<table data-toggle="table" data-height="700" data-classes="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr class="info"> <!--it doesn't work-->
            <th>Item ID</th>
            <th>Item Name</th>
            <th>Item Price</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>0</th>
            <th>Item 0</th>
            <th>10</th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Please help. How can I change style for header bootstrap-table?

P.S. if use bootstrap without wenzhixin bootstrap-table, then everything works, but to me it is necessary wenzhixin bootstrap-table

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. `bootstrap-table` removes the classes and styles from the `thead`, `tr`, `th` tags. This is more than frustrating if you also use [stickyTableHeaders](https://github.com/jmosbech/StickyTableHeaders) (the background will not be white but transparent).
`bootstrap-table` provides a `load-success` event, which fires after the table has been rendered. You can use this to attach the class/style to your table afterwards. Be aware that your table needs an `id`

```
$('#myTable').on('load-success.bs.table', function (e, data) {
    $('#myTable').stickyTableHeaders();
    $('#myTable thead tr').css('background','white');
});
```

So to complete your snip, something like this should work:

```
<table id="myTable" data-toggle="table" data-height="700" data-classes="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr class="info"> <!--it doesn't work-->
            <th>Item ID</th>
            <th>Item Name</th>
            <th>Item Price</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>0</th>
            <th>Item 0</th>
            <th>10</th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script>
    $('#myTable').on('load-success.bs.table', function (e, data) {
        $('#myTable thead tr').css('background','pink');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: The header can still be modified after `load-success.bs.table` fires. Instead, consider binding to `post-header.bs.table`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the `data-classes` attribute, if you use only `class`, the problem is solved on firefox, chrome and ie7+.

Regards, hope it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check with:

```
<style>
       #tableID thead tr{
          background-color: #0361cc; color:white;
       }
</style>
```

Comment: I had to also add th selector. ex `#compTable thead tr, th{
 background-color: #e9f9ee !important;
}`